# how to use two List<> as datasource of a repeater at the same time asp.net

Tags: asp.net, list, datasource, eval, repeater

I am trying to display data of two different List<> with a repeater. Secondary list must be displayed in a column of the table inside of the repeater. Both number of List<>'s items are same.I will be happy if you guys give me the solution or another method for solving.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand.  Are you saying you have 2 lists and you want a table with two columns, one for each list displayed in the repeater?

Comment: post some code about list definition and what do you want about repeater?

Comment: Adam   2 different lists for 2 columns.

Comment: @Berzingen Have you had a chance to check out/try my answer below? If so, did you have any issues?

Comment: thank you but probably you dont understand . I solved tihs problem with creating a table with LINQ join and convert the list to datatable

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the 2 string lists into an object list like so:

Make a new class that has 2 strings as properties like so (this can be in your current page code behind file if you want but should be outside of that page's class declaration - e.g. below the end if the page class):

```
class TwoStrings
{
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is some sample code to take 2 lists of strings (like you currently have) and brings them together in a `List` of the `TwoStrings` class.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

//Some sample data
list1.Add("1");
list2.Add("one");
list1.Add("2");
list2.Add("two");

List<TwoStrings> TwoStringList = new List<TwoStrings>();

//This is assumimg both lists are always the same length
for (int index = 0; index <= list1.Count - 1; index++) {
    TwoStrings ts = new TwoStrings();
    ts.String1 = list1(index);
    ts.String2 = list2(index);
    TwoStringList.Add(ts);
}

Repeater1.DataSource = TwoStringList;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Here's a sample of what your repeater might look like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("String1")%>' />
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("String2")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```